# How to monitor IO svctm with every 5 mins frequency using nagios?

Tags: nagios, performance-monitoring, io

I want to collect samples of `iostat`'s `svctm`, `await` every 5 mins from all of my servers and store them in nagios. I want to get the values for what is happening in every 5 minutes (not since boot time, `iostat`'s first output gives values since boot time). How can I do it in nagios?

**EDIT**
The tps should NOT be calculated #of transactions happened since reboot divided by uptime. What I want is # of transferred happened in last X mins divided X*60.

Comment: Nagios can *alert* you on this, but it's pretty crappy and long-term data trending (e.g., graphing). You might want to consider something like cacti for this.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios has a plugin to check iostat: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_iostat--2D-I-2FO-statistics/details

You'll also need to configure nagios to collect [performance data](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/perfdata.html)

and run the checks every 5 minutes by setting [check_interval](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/objectdefinitions.html#service) to 5

Comment: Edited the question. Basically I don't want tps getting averaged out since uptime.